# port number of an UDP socket

Tags: c, sockets, udp, port, sockaddr-in

My OS is Ubuntu 20.x .
I have two programs :  `server.c` that listens to `INADDR_ANY` on the port `2052` and `client.c` that sends UDP packets locally on `INADDR_LOOPBACK` at the same port.

The programs works fine and the received data and IP address match the sent ones; however
the port numbers do not match. I can see with `netstat` that `server.c` is listening at the correct port (`2052`) and I convert the port number to the local endianess so I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

`server.c` :

```c
#define MY_PORT 2052

int main (void)
{
    int socket_descriptor = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    struct sockaddr_in server_socket = {.sin_addr = {.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY)}, .sin_port = htons(MY_PORT), .sin_family = AF_INET, .sin_zero = {0}};

    bind(socket_descriptor, (struct sockaddr *) &server_socket, sizeof(server_socket));


    char client_msg[SIZE + 1] = {0};
    struct sockaddr_in client_socket;
    socklen_t addrlen = sizeof(client_socket);


    ssize_t received_bytes = recvfrom(socket_descriptor, client_msg, SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &client_socket, &addrlen);

    // this prints the data sent as expected : 
    printf("received %ld bytes of data : data was %s\n", received_bytes, client_msg);
    // this prints 127.0.0.1 as expected :
    printf("the client IP address was %s\n", inet_ntop(AF_INET, &client_socket.sin_addr, (char [INET_ADDRSTRLEN]) {0},  INET_ADDRSTRLEN));
    // this prints the WRONG port :
    printf("the port was %d\n", ntohs(client_socket.sin_port));
    
    close(socket_descriptor);
}
```

`client.c` :

```c
#define MY_PORT 2052

int main (void)
{
    int socket_descriptor = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

    struct sockaddr_in client_socket = {.sin_port = htons(MY_PORT), .sin_family = AF_INET, .sin_addr = {.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK)}, .sin_zero = {0}};

    char buffer[SIZE] = "this is a test message";

    sendto(socket_descriptor, buffer, SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&client_socket, sizeof(client_socket));

    close(socket_descriptor);
}
```

My goal is to get the correct port number on the listening (server) side. Thanks for your help !

Comment: the posted code does not compile!   first. because both programs are missing the needed `#include` statements for the needed header files.  Are you expecting us to guess as to which header files (if any) that your programs actually used?

Comment: OT: regarding: `char buffer[SIZE] = "this is a test message";
    sendto(socket_descriptor, buffer, SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&client_socket, sizeof(client_socket));`   `SIZE` is not defined and why have it defined.  Instead, let the compiler determine the size.  Suggest:  `char buffer[] = "this is a test message"; sendto(socket_descriptor, buffer, sizeof( buffer ), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&client_socket, sizeof(client_socket));`

Comment: OT:  regarding: `ssize_t received_bytes = recvfrom(socket_descriptor, client_msg, SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &client_socket, &addrlen);` The code should be error checking the returned value `received_bytes`  If == 0 then other end of connection closed.  if < 0 then some communication error and should use `perror()` to output your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.

Comment: @user3629249 The post below already answered my question. My actual code was  of course way longer than these samples, because of the return value checking and the tons of `#include`. I was assuming the error had to be trivial enough for an experienced programmer to see it without even compiling the program, which proved to be true. Thanks for your input though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The port number that the server is printing is the *client's* port number.  This is different from the server's port number.  The server can then use this port number to send a response back to the client.

Also, when sending a UDP datagram, if you don't bind to a specific port the system will chose one at random.

Comment: ... and the client could not bind to the same port the server is already bound to anyway.

Comment: Thanks, I had completely misunderstood how ports worked :c